# MVC4 Validation Description

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

Here is an image from the XBox account details web page.

[image: An input box from the XBox website]

Notice that under the textbox there is an extra instruction "Max Length 21 characters".  This is displayed when the entry is **valid**.  When the entry is **not valid**, this text is replaced by a validation message.

I can test the control by checking for the 'field-validation-valid' class in the validation span associated with it the input box.

But when to do this?

If I handle the **keydown** event for the textbox, I get the event before the validation is complete.  So my display lags 1 key press behind.

If I handle the **changed** event, it is only fired when the focus is lost, whereas the validation is done at every key press.

Any ideas how I could do this in MVC4?  The jQuery unobtrusive validation seems to be a closed box.

Thanks!

Comment: by default asp.net mvc4 provides you unobtrusive validation. is it ok if i post answer for jquery validation ?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.  I'm using the data attributes so I need the unobtrusive validation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add these keys to web.config.

> ```
> <appSettings>
>         <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
>         <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
>     </appSettings>
> ```

then include these files in your layout page (or even include those path in BundleCollection)

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

Make sure you have decorated your model with data-annotations, for eg:

```
public class someClass
{
   [Required]
   [StringLength(40)]
   public string username{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is an answer to the question "Why isn't my client-side validation working in MVC4".